# Removal of items with duplicate data

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a function that removes the consecutive items with duplicate data . 
e.g 
For example, passing in the list

> ->a->b->c->c->a->b->b->b->a->null

should result in

> ->a->b->c->a->b->a->null

The list item definition and function declaration are given below

```
struct litem { 
char data; 
litem* next; 
};
```

Mo code looks like

```
int remove_dumplicates(litem *&list)
{
 int count = 0; 
 struct litem * current = NULL;
 current = list;
 struct  litem *deleteNode;
 if (current == NULL ) return;
 while(current->next != NULL)
 {
  if ( current->data == current->next->data) // check for the duplicates 
   {
    count++;
    deleteNode =current->next;
    current>next= current->next->next;
    delete deleteNode;
   }      
  return (count);  
 }
}
```

Is this a correct way of achieving the desired result ?

Comment: Please format your code correctly first.

Comment: The `return` statement might be outside the `while` loop. And, a statement like `current = current->next;` is required there.

Comment: Have you tested on common and edge cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `current` being incremented to `current->next`.

Take as an example a list with all unique elements `a -> b -> c` and see how your program works.

To fix this you need:

```
while(current->next != NULL) {
   if ( current->data == current->next->data) {
     // delete duplicates .
   } else {
     current = current -> next;
   }
}// end-while
return (count);
```

Comment: Why the `current = current->next;` is inside `else` rather than unconditional?

Comment: @Arun: The duplicates are removed inside a `if` and not a `while` so we need to stay at the current position to see if there are more duplicates.

Comment: We could also do `while(current->data == current->next->data)..remove duplicate` in that case current increment will be unconditional as we are sure that all the duplicates are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an else inside the while loop to advance to the next node:

```
if( current-> data == current->next->data ) {
....
} else {
    current = current->next;
}
```

Also the returns need to be fixed (the first should return 0 and the second should be moved outside the while loop).

Comment: Why the `current = current->next;` is inside `else` rather than unconditional?

Comment: To take care of multiple duplicates (a->a->a->b)

Answer (score 1):

1. current should move to current->next on no duplicate match.
2. Argument passed to the function should be merely *list (ie. a pointer to an element of type struct litem)
3. `delete` is a C++ keyword. Use `free()` instead.

The modified code:

```
int remove_duplicates(struct litem *list)
{
    int count = 0; 
    struct litem * current = NULL;
    current = list;
    struct  litem *deleteNode;
    if (current == NULL ) return;
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        if ( current->data == current->next->data) 
        {
            count++;
            deleteNode = current->next;
                current->next= current->next->next;
                    free(deleteNode);
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return (count);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some quick observations:

The `return (count)` statement might be outside the `while` loop, otherwise the loop would be terminated prematurely.

A statement like `current = current->next;` is required inside the `while` loop. Otherwise, the loop would become an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int remove_duplicates(litem *&list)
{
   int count = 0; 
   struct litem * current = NULL;
   current = list;
   struct  litem *deleteNode;
   if (current == NULL ) return 0;
   while(current->next != NULL)
   {
     if (current->data == current->next->data) // check for the duplicates 
     {
       count++;
       deleteNode =current->next;
       current->next= current->next->next;
       delete deleteNode;
     }
     else
     {
       current = current->next;
     }
   }
   return (count);
 }
```